# Cannot build osmdroid repository

Tags: android, android-studio, osmdroid, jcenter

I have cloned the osmdroid repository from 
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid
and I am unable to get it to build. I'm focussed on the OpenStreetMapViewer project in the repository.

I think the source of the problem is that I cannot use maven because I am behind a firewall. For all Android Studio projects I have created or cloned, I have to modify the build.gradle by removing
`mavenCentral` and instead use:

```
jcenter {
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

For this project, `build.gradle` includes this line in the `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:22.2.+'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:4.3'
}
```

However, browsing jcenter here:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter
I do not see v4, only v7 (android-support-v7-appcompat)

I tried v7 as a dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

which the requires changing the `compileskdversion` to 23.

Doing that I get this build error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'OpenStreetMapViewer'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve android.support:compatibility-v4:21.0.3.
     Required by:
         :OpenStreetMapViewer:unspecified > org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:4.3
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/android/support/compatibility-v4/21.0.3/compatibility-v4-21.0.3.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:22.0.0.
     Required by:
         :OpenStreetMapViewer:unspecified > org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:4.3
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/google-play-services/22.0.0/google-play-services-22.0.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated
```

So it appears that osmdroid really needs v4, not v7

In the Android SDK Manager, I have installed Extras > Android Support Repository 22 and > Android Support Library 23.0.1

What can I do?

Edit -------------------------------------------
I guess I should have started the question with the error the occurs when attempting to import the project without modifying any build.gradle or manifest. The point being that the instructions on "How to Maven" don't work in this case.

```
Error: Cause: peer not authenticated
Untrusted Server's certificate - Server's certificate not trusted.
Issued to: Common Name plugins.jetgrains.com
Organization: Jetbrains.s.r.o
Locality: Praha 4 - Nusle
Country: CZ
ST: Praha 4 - Nusle
```

Edit 2 --------------------------------------------------------------
As stated previously, I cloned osmdroid from here:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid
I set the system environment variable M2_HOME to the location of the cloned osmdroid project.

In settings.xml:

```
<localRepository>D:\Users\myusername\AndroidstudioProjects\maven-android-sdk-deployer</localRepository>
```

I downloaded maven from here:
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
Unzipped D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin, which I then also included in the `path` system variable.

In a DOS window, I go to M2_HOME and execute this command:

> mvn install

I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/simpligility/maven/progressive-organization-pom/3.0.0/progressive-organization-pom-3.0.0.pom

[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.simpligility.android.sdk-deployer:maven-android-sdk-deployer:2.8.0: Could not transfer artifact com.simpligility.maven:progressive-organization-pom:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11
@ 
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

The project com.simpligility.android.sdk-deployer:maven-android-sdk-deployer:2.8.0 (D:\maven-android-sdk-deployer\pom.xml) has 1 error
Non-resolvable parent POM for com.simpligility.android.sdk-deployer:maven-android-sdk-deployer:2.8.0: Could not transfer artifact com.simpligility.maven:progressive-organization-pom:pom:3.0.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 11 -> [Help 2]

[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Edit 3 -----------------------------------------------------------
In `D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\conf/settings.xml`, I added:

```
<localRepository>D:\Users\myusername\AndroidstudioProjects\maven-android-sdk-deployer</localRepository>
```

This didn't make any difference. Is it correct to do this?

Edit 4 ------------------------------------------------------------
Tried adding parameters to the command for certs:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```

Edit 5 -------------------------------------------------------------
All of the above may have been necessary but not sufficient. What got it working was having the network persons add an exception to the firewall for maven and adding Sun Certs.
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Edit 6 --------------------------------------------------------------
Set M2_HOME to location of maven, e.g.:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\
Add location of mvn command to Path in System variables:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Osmdroid uses maven. (see https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/HowToMaven)

Basically, you need to get maven (at least version 3.2.1), the maven-android-sdk-deployer (https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer) and the osmdroid code.

`git clone https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer`

`cd maven-android-sdk-deployer`

`mvn install -fn`

Build osmdroid

`git clone https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid.git`

`cd osmdroid`

`mvn clean install`

Edit: There are some gradle support files for the example application, but you'll need to build the rest of the stuff using maven first. The gradle bits are there for convenance with android studio.

Edit: if you're on a windows box. try the following

Path for maven

```
set M2_HOME=D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3
set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\whereever\android-sdk
```

Path for the maven-android-sdk-deployer

```
cd D:\...\maven-android-sdk-deployer
```

Run the deployer

```
mvn install -fn
```

Build osmdroid

```
cd D:\...\osmdroid
mvn clean install`
```

Another option:

I recently just pushed some gradle support files along with the gradle wrapper. It only builds the bare minimum at the moment but it may get you going.

`git clone https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid.git`

`cd osmdroid`

`gradlew build`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have now cloned from https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer.
So then I get the `error 'mvn' is not a recognized as an internal or external command.`
I added system environment variables ANDROID_HOME (point to the SDK) and M2_HOME (pointing to where I cloned), but this did not help.
What next? (windows 7, btw)

Comment: Progress ... see Edit 2 above ...  do you know what's going wrong now?

Comment: Wrong directory. Need to be in the same dir as a pom

Comment: The value for`M2_HOME`? If I set it to the directory of the pom.xml, I get "Please set the M2_HOME variable to match the location of the Maven installation"

Comment: M2 is where you unzipped maven to.  The working dir needs to be where the maven sdk deployed is

Comment: I have 2 maven-related directories:  
(1) D:\Users\myusername\AndroidstudioProjects\maven-android-sdk-deployer, contains pom.xml  
(2) D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3  
  
`M2` is set to (1) which contains pom.xml  
`M2_HOME` is set to (2),   

As stated previously, If I reverse this, ie set `M2` to (2) and MS_HOME`  to (1), then I get the error that `M2_HOME` must be set to match the location of the Maven installation.  

As it is, I get the `Non-resolvable parent POM` error above.

Comment: the apache-maven folder should not contain a pom. 

 see the answer above, comments don't support formatting apparently

Comment: pom.xml is in `cd D:\...\maven-android-sdk-deployer`. I followed the instructions in your edit. I still get the "Non-resolvable parent POM" error with the command `mvn install -fn'

Comment: Tried something in settings.xml. See Edit 3

Comment: Edit 3, unnecessary. I just updated my answer and have pushed minimal gradle support files, just for you. Suggest you give maven one more shot, then attempt the gradle based build (osmdroid's support for gradle is still incomplete)

Comment: The link  https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/HowToMaven is not there any more. Do you know where it is now?

Comment: osmdroid now uses gradle. The maven setup hasn't worked since April 2016

Answer (score 1):

The SDK libraries (inc. the com.android.support:appcompat) are not available in JCenter (or any other repository for that matter), not ver7 and not ver4. They are part of the SDK and need to be pre-installed. See [this official doc](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) for more info.